# PutLong on a null Long in argument Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, null, long-integer

Given a new instance method of a Fragment:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Long someLong) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    MyFragment fragment = new WorkoutDetailsRoutineInfoFragment();
    args.putLong(ARGS_LONG, someLong);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

If `someLong` is null, this doesn't work.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

How do I get it to store the Long even if it's null?

Comment: why do you need it? If you will not store it, it will mean that it is null

Comment: Because sometimes it's null, sometimes it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if its null and if its null add -1 if its not null add the Long object. Pretty easy

Comment: Yes, your answer may solve the question in some cases, but it isn't as straightforward as you made it seem. Your solution only works because you ASSUMED that numbers less than zero don't mean anything in the writer's code, and so he can use -1 to denote a null.